# for文中で実際には利用されていない変数

Tags: python

素数を見つけるジェネレータ関数とそれを利用する以下のソースコードにおいて

```
for c in range(10):
  print(next(i))
```

というコードのcをどこで利用しているのかがどうしても理解できません。
なぜcという繰り返し変数を１度添えただけで素数が１０まで表示されるのでしょうか？
どなたか教えて頂けませんでしょうか

```
def get_primes(x=2):
  while True:
    for i in range(2,x):
      if x % i == 0:
        break
    else:
      yield x
    x += 1

i = get_primes()
for c in range(10):
  print(next(i))

2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

Comment: `for c in range(10):` は、Cは、０～９の値にセットされてループしますが、１０回のループをすること（`print(next(i))`を１０回実行すること）自体が目的なので、実際には使用されません。

Comment: 例えば `for _ in range(10):` としてもよいです。

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
今シェルで確認いたしました。１０回ループするという命令で変数はCでなくてもいいのだと改めて分かりました。
こんなに早く教えてくださりありがとうございました！！！！

Comment: argusさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
_を用いると繰り返すだけという感じでとても分かりやすいですね！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

すでにコメントがある通り、`c` は使われていません。形式上そこに変数が必要なので `c` が使われているようです。

ただ、Python では、このような代入はされども参照されない変数には `_` もしくは、`dummy` という変数名を使うことが多いです。[Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) のような文法チェックツールでは、参照されない変数に警告が出ますが、`_` や `dummy` といった変数には警告が出ないようになっています。